# unable to change data of an array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

It's some javascript related issue (not angular but context is angular), trying to sort out for hours without any success.

I'm trimming down the content to shorter paragraphs and assigning the subcontent back to the array's content property but it's still the larger contents that shows up.

```
controller: function($scope, $location) {
    this.$scope = $scope;

    this.$scope.folio = {
        "deleted"       : null,
        "free"          : null,
        "id"            : null,
        "lastModified"  : null,
        "productId"     : null,
        "publication"   : null,

        articles: []
    };
},

result: function(folio) {
    this.$scope.folio.articles.length = 0;

    this.$scope.folio.deleted = folio.deleted
    this.$scope.folio.free = folio.free
    this.$scope.folio.id = folio.id
    this.$scope.folio.lastModified = folio.lastModified
    this.$scope.folio.productId = folio.productId
    this.$scope.folio.publication = folio.publication

    for(var i=0; i<folio.articles.length; i++) {

        for(var j=0; j<folio.articles[i].pages.length; j++) {
            var content = folio.articles[i].pages[j].content
            var index = content.toLowerCase().indexOf("test".toLowerCase())

            if(index > 150) { //if index is not within first 150 characters
                content = content.substring(index - 25, index + 30)
            }
            //displays fine with the desired output
            console.log(content.replace(new RegExp("test", "gi"), "<em>" + "test" + "</em>"))

            //assigning back to the array but for some reason it's not the trimmed output at the end
            folio.articles[i].pages[j].content = content.replace(new RegExp("test", "gi"), "<em>" + "test" + "</em>")
        }

        //the article's pages are still full length
        this.$scope.folio.articles.push(folio.articles[i]); 
    }

    this.$scope.$apply();
}
```

Comment: Your question is broad, but I don't see how

result: function(folio) connects to controller: function($scope, $location)

I presume this is only part of the program.

Comment: to trim it down, if you can please bring into scope only the loop `j` part and then the assignment back followed by `$scope.$apply()` that's where I've the problem, the rest is ignorable context, and even a simple assignment back to `folio.articles[i].pages[j].content` is not taking effect

Comment: It connects by "this", and, my suggestion is, remove the "this". Put the function inside the controller, and everything will be like "$scope.yourNamedFunction" or "$scope.yourAttribute". I'm still developing the ideas here, to give you a full answer.

Comment: I know the approach is different, as behind the scenes I'm using an mvc framework on top of angular, but the problem isn't in the angular implementation part, it's 99.5% working, funny that I can't mutate the array content property

Answer (score 0):

This should help you update your content.

```
(function(angular){
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp');

    myApp.controller('Controller', function(){
        $scope.folio = {
            "deleted"       : null,
            "free"          : null,
            "id"            : null,
            "lastModified"  : null,
            "productId"     : null,
            "publication"   : null,

            articles: []
        };

        $scope.result = function(folio) {
            $scope.folio = folio;

            angular.forEach($scope.folio.articles, function(article, articleIndex)) {
                angular.forEach(article.pages, function(page, pageIndex)) {
                    var content = page.content,
                        index = content.toLowerCase().indexOf("test".toLowerCase());

                    if(index > 150) { //if index is not within first 150 characters
                        content = content.substring(index - 25, index + 30)
                    }
                    //displays fine with the desired output
                    console.log(content.replace(new RegExp("test", "gi"), "<em>" + "test" + "</em>"))

                    //assigning back to the array but for some reason it's not the trimmed output at the end
                    $scope.folio.articles[i].pages[j].content = content.replace(new RegExp("test", "gi"), "<em>" + "test" + "</em>")
                }

                $scope.folio.articles.push(folio.articles[i]); 
            }

            $scope.$apply();
        }
    });

})(window.angular);
```

Do not forget to use `ng-app="myApp"` and `ng-controller="ControllerName"` in your HTML.